# css transform scale keep onscreen

Tags: html, css, image, transform

I have a series of images on-screen in bootstrap 3 panels (3 per row for large screens).

When you click on an image I have it set up so that it applies a CSS class which does a 'scale(2)' on the image, this all works fine, but I want those images to be visible and scale themselves on screen.

Images in column 1 end up slightly off-screen to the left, Images in column 3 end up slightly off-screen to the right, Images in column 2 are for the most part fine.

Ideally I would like them to scale into the centre of the viewport itself, or at least just not render off-screen at all.

CSS:

```
  .zoom {      
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;    
    -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;    
    transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;     
    cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;      
    cursor: -moz-zoom-in;      
    cursor: zoom-in;  
  }   

  .zoom-click {
    -ms-transform: scale(2);
    -moz-transform: scale(2);  
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);  
    -o-transform: scale(2);  
    transform: scale(2); 
    position:relative;
    z-index:100; 
    border: 2px solid DarkRed; 
  }
```

Upon clicking on the image it adds/removes the 'zoom-click' class.

I have tried using 'translate' along with the 'scale' however it is relative to the image itself, have also tried using 'transform-origin'.

**Update: ** Have created a jsfiddle showing how it is at present (minus the knockoutjs code which actually creates each of the 'main-image-panel' panels.

https://jsfiddle.net/tczh1sxq/2/

Comment: when hover, image should show out of div? or can me zoomed inside div?

Comment: The image pops out from where it is currently and gets scaled to 2x its current size. Also it only happens when you click on an image not when you hover.

Comment: I have updated my answer with new fiddler. check it once.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. I always seem to have difficulty at times with the more complex CSS.

Anyway, fixed it by doing:

```
  #images > div .zoom-click { transform-origin: top; }
  #images > div:nth-child(3n+0) .zoom-click { transform-origin: top right; }
  #images > div:nth-child(3n+1) .zoom-click { transform-origin: top left; }
```

Be nice if I could get it to actually go into the centre of the viewport, but this will suffice, looks much neater now that it isn't off-screen on the edges.

Comment: This one i suggested yesterday itself dude!

Comment: Indeed you did, though because I hadn't done a jsfiddle at the time showing what I had done, what you suggested didn't make much sense to me, especially since it wasn't on the right elements (that's my fault not yours). The problem is I can't mark your original one as the answer because it's all done in JS now.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea tried to resolve your issue. I used different tranform-origin based on child element index value as like nth-child,

```
$('.child').click(function(){
    var index = $(this).index()+1;
    if((index%3)==1){
        $(this).find('img').css({
        'transform': 'scale(2)',
        'transform-origin': 'top left'
      });
    }
    else if((index%3)==2){
        $(this).find('img').css({
        'transform': 'scale(2)',
        'transform-origin': 'top'
      });
    }
    else if((index%3)==0){
        $(this).find('img').css({
        'transform': 'scale(2)',
        'transform-origin': 'top right'
      });
    }
  });
```

Find this [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/rajsnd08/sxpgvLpm/4/) for reference.

Comment: Would that still work even though I have no 'row' div? Technically speaking i'm not hard limiting it, I just throw divs onto the screen with 'col-md-4' and let Bootstrap determine how many it can fit onto the screen depending on screenwidth. It is an option though, I could just wrap every 3 divs in a row-div since I know this particular part of the system will never be viewed on a mobile device.

Comment: then you can achieve it by using nth-child element. find the update fiddler in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

this might help,

```css
.zoom-click
{
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

}
You can use any height/ width you want. If the image is contained within any positioned element, you can use position: fixed and it will still work